# JTextPane - turning off last Style

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

i want to color some keywords in JTextPane. But I dont want to keep the same style after these words

```
while (regexMatcher.find()){
            int start = regexMatcher.start();
            int end = regexMatcher.end();

            document.setCharacterAttributes(start, end-start, style, false);
        }
```

It works however when I click right after the last char and type something that has same style but want to change back to default.

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `CaretChangeListener` to the `JTextPane`. On each caret update you should clear input attributes of the EditorKit installed in the `JTextPane`.

```
MutableAttributeSet inputAttributes=((StyledEditorKit)pane.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();
//remove all the unwanted style attributes
```